# Handle previous state in continuous rotation

Tags: math, lua, trigonometry

Hello i have the following lua code which functionality is to rotate a point creating a circle. The problem I'm having is with initial and/or last state. Since there is a clock running whenever i stop the rotation and start again, the point jumps around. I tried saving the last value after the lfo is turned off, and then use this value in each sin and cos functions but i cannot make it work well.

Thank you!

[image: Text]

The Code:

```
local last = 0
local trigger = false

function update()
t = getMillis()
T = 3000
  if trigger == true then
    x = math.cos(2*math.pi*( (t - last) + t) /T)
    y = math.sin(2*math.pi*( (t - last) + t) /T)
  end
end

function onValueChanged(key)
  if key == "x" and self.values.x == 1 then
    if trigger == true then
      last = t
    end
  trigger = not trigger
 end
end
```

Comment: Where does the `t` in `onValueChanged` come from?

Comment: What is probably intended is `angle = last_angle + angular_speed*(time - trigger_time)`.